# Symfony 2 - In production not return POST Json custom message exception

Tags: symfony, exception, symfony-2.8, custom-exceptions

I'm using Symfony 2.8

I have a POST method root. The return format is json.

```
app_patient_create:
path: /
methods: [POST]
defaults:
    _controller: App:Patient:create
    _format: json
    _angular_safe: true
```

In a Listener in this root, i have an exception.

```
throw new Exception\MaxPointsException();
```

This is the custom exception :

```
namespace App\Training\Exception;

class MaxPointsException extends \LogicException
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Vous avez atteint le nombre maximal de patients inclus dans votre offre découverte. Pour continuer à profiter du site, veuillez vous abonner');
    }
}
```

In dev environnement, the message is return :

[image]

But not in prod environnement :

[image]

Did you know why?

Comment: only in dev mode full error message is returned, in prod mode only 500 (internal server error) is return to avoid the disclosure of sensitive information which could help a bad guy. make sure you return HTTP error messages which are validated.

Comment: Thank you, i use a HTTP 409 for recognize my exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an HTTP 409 reponse for recognize my exception.